# Activity associated with image cropping libraries does not destroy

Tags: android, image

I have tried to solve this problem from many different links but does not worked for me.I am using Android Image Cropper library for cropping images. Whenever i click on the button "upload image" it start the cropping activity and when i am done the cropped image is set in an imageview in "upload image" activity and after clicking "Proceed" button login is successful and i am directed to login activity but when i back press the login activity the "Upload image" activity is still there and is not destroyed. I have another activity called Update Activity  that uses this Cropping activity and that activity also behaves in the same manner. So i want the "Upload image" to destroy. Thanks in advance

```js
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;



public class CroppingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CropImageView mCropImageView;

    public static Bitmap finalImage = null;
    public static Bitmap newImage = null;
    private Uri mCropImageUri;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_crop);
        mCropImageView = (CropImageView) findViewById(R.id.CropImageView);

    }

    /**
     * On load image button click, start pick image chooser activity.
     */
    public void onLoadImageClick(View view) {
        startActivityForResult(getPickImageChooserIntent(), 200);
    }

    public void  onSetImageClick(View view) {

        if(UpdateActivity.UpdatingPhoto){
            newImage = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(200, 200);
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UpdateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CroppingActivity.this, "Oppss..Error occured.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else {
            finalImage = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(200, 200);
            try {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadImage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(CroppingActivity.this, "Oppss..Error occured.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    /**
     * Crop the image and set it back to the cropping view.
     */
    public void onCropImageClick(View view) {
        Bitmap cropped = mCropImageView.getCroppedImage(500, 500);
        if (cropped != null)
            mCropImageView.setImageBitmap(cropped);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageUri = getPickImageResultUri(data);

            // For API >= 23 we need to check specifically that we have permissions to read external storage,
            // but we don't know if we need to for the URI so the simplest is to try open the stream and see if we get error.
            boolean requirePermissions = false;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    isUriRequiresPermissions(imageUri)) {

                // request permissions and handle the result in onRequestPermissionsResult()
                requirePermissions = true;
                mCropImageUri = imageUri;
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 0);
            }
            if (!requirePermissions) {
                mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        UpdateActivity.UpdatingPhoto = false;
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        if (mCropImageUri != null && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mCropImageView.setImageUriAsync(mCropImageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Required permissions are not granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create a chooser intent to select the source to get image from.<br/>
     * The source can be camera's (ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE) or gallery's (ACTION_GET_CONTENT).<br/>
     * All possible sources are added to the intent chooser.
     */
    public Intent getPickImageChooserIntent() {

        // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
        Uri outputFileUri = getCaptureImageOutputUri();

        List<Intent> allIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

        // collect all camera intents
        Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listCam) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            if (outputFileUri != null) {
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            }
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // collect all gallery intents
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> listGallery = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(galleryIntent, 0);
        for (ResolveInfo res : listGallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(galleryIntent);
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            intent.setPackage(res.activityInfo.packageName);
            allIntents.add(intent);
        }

        // the main intent is the last in the list (Foolish android) so pickup the useless one
        Intent mainIntent = allIntents.get(allIntents.size() - 1);
        for (Intent intent : allIntents) {
            if (intent.getComponent().getClassName().equals("com.android.documentsui.DocumentsActivity")) {
                mainIntent = intent;
                break;
            }
        }
        allIntents.remove(mainIntent);

        // Create a chooser from the main intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(mainIntent, "Select source");

        // Add all other intents
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, allIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[allIntents.size()]));

        return chooserIntent;
    }

    /**
     * Get URI to image received from capture by camera.
     */
    private Uri getCaptureImageOutputUri() {
        Uri outputFileUri = null;
        File getImage = getExternalCacheDir();
        if (getImage != null) {
            outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getImage.getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
        }
        return outputFileUri;
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI of the selected image from {@link #getPickImageChooserIntent()}.<br/>
     * Will return the correct URI for camera and gallery image.
     *
     * @param data the returned data of the activity result
     */
    public Uri getPickImageResultUri(Intent data) {
        boolean isCamera = true;
        if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            String action = data.getAction();
            isCamera = action != null && action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
        return isCamera ? getCaptureImageOutputUri() : data.getData();
    }

    /**
     * Test if we can open the given Android URI to test if permission required error is thrown.<br>
     */
    public boolean isUriRequiresPermissions(Uri uri) {
        try {
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
            InputStream stream = resolver.openInputStream(uri);
            stream.close();
            return false;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof ErrnoException) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
package com.donateblood.blooddonation;

    public double longitude;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.uploadimage);
        code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        myimage = CroppingActivity.finalImage;
        CheckImage();
        // Upload image ====================================
        Btn_Upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CroppingActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Btn_Proceed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(code.length()==0){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Enter verification code", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Prcoess();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public  void CheckImage(){
        if(myimage!=null){
            // set the image
            // myimage = getRoundedShape(myimage);
            Uri uri = getImageUri(myimage);
            String url = getRealPathFromURI(uri);
            File file = new File(url);
            Picasso.with(UploadImage.this).load(file).resize(200,200).placeholder(R.drawable.user).error(R.drawable.error)
                    .transform(new CircleTransform()).centerCrop()
                    .into(ImageUpload);
        }else {
            encodedPhotoString= null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (pDialog != null) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            pDialog = null;
        }
    }


    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = UploadImage.this.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    public Uri getImageUri( Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(UploadImage.this.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    // Processing and adding user to database from here ====================================
    public void Prcoess(){
        String userentered=code.getText().toString();
        String sentcode = SignupActivity.Code;

        // resize the image to store to database
        //myimage=  getResizedBitmap(myimage,200,200);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        myimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
        byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        encodedPhotoString = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, 0);

        if(userentered.equals(sentcode) && encodedPhotoString!=null ){
            new AddUserAsync().execute();
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong code or No image uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    public class AddUserAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
        JSONObject json =null;
        boolean added = false;


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(UploadImage.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            GetUserDetails();
            GenerateGCMID();
            email= email.trim().toLowerCase();
            HashMap<String ,String> userDetails = new HashMap<>();
            latitude = GPSTracker.getLatitude();
            longitude =  GPSTracker.getLongitude();

            userDetails.put("ID",ID);
            userDetails.put("Name",name);
            userDetails.put("email",email);
            userDetails.put("password",password);
            userDetails.put("age",age);
            userDetails.put("number",number);
            userDetails.put("bloodgroup",bloodgroup);
            userDetails.put("lat",latitude+"");
            userDetails.put("longi",longitude+"");
            userDetails.put("image",encodedPhotoString);
            json = new HttpCall().postForJSON("http://abdulbasit.website/blood_app/Adduser.php",userDetails);

            if(json!=null){
                added = true;
            }else {
                added = false;
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if(added==true){

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            onSignupSuccess();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Error creating account. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
    public void GenerateGCMID(){
        GCMClientManager pushClientManager = new GCMClientManager(this, "921544902369");
        pushClientManager.registerIfNeeded(new GCMClientManager.RegistrationCompletedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String registrationId, boolean isNewRegistration) {
                Log.d("Registration id", registrationId);
                ID = registrationId;
                Log.e("reg",ID);
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(String ex) {
                super.onFailure(ex);
            }
        });
    }
    // Go to another activity on success ====================================
    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        // stop the service we got the latitude and longitude now
        stopService(new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class));
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    // fetch user details ====================================
    public void GetUserDetails(){

        bloodgroup = SignupActivity.bloodgroup.toString();
        name = SignupActivity.name.toString();
        email = SignupActivity.email.toString();
        password = SignupActivity.password.toString();
        number = SignupActivity.number.toString();
        age = SignupActivity.age.toString();
    }


    // Resize the image ====================================
    public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth)
    {
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
        // create a matrix for the manipulation
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        // resize the bit map
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        // recreate the new Bitmap
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this method you are not finishing the UploadActivity here:-

```
Btn_Upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CroppingActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            UploadActivity.this.finish();  

        }
    });
```

Comment: Ohhh Thank You so much. Worked fine :-)